# Java JFrame.setState(Normal) -- JComponents grayed out, textfields unclickable

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcomponent

I have a program that first minimizes the current JFrame window and reopens it:

```
JFrame.setState(Frame.ICONIFIED);
JFrame.setState(Frame.NORMAL);
```

However, after reopening the JFrame window all of the inner `JComponents` become `grayed` out and `JTextfields` become uneditable.

Problem Images:

[image: After the JFrame is Minimized and Reopened]

However, if I manually minimize and reopen the Java Application all of the `JComponents` become blueish and I am able to edit them.

After manually minimizing and reopening Java Application:

[image: After manually minimizing and reopening Java Application]

I have tried to set all of the `JComponents` `setVisible`, `setEnabled`, `setEditable`, `setFocusable` to `true` but nothing works.

Solutions:

[image: Solutions]

Comment: Can you post some code showing how you create your JFrame object? Thanks.

Comment: *I have tried to set all of the JComponents setVisible, setEnabled, setEditable, setFocusable to true but nothing works.* - there is no need for any of that code. Those properties are set to true by default (except for the JFrame which you need to make visible). The picture you post tell us nothing about your code. Post a [mre] demonstrating the problem. That is create a JFrame with a single JTextField and the logic you use to iconify and restore the frame, so we can see exactly what happens.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to figure it out. I used the following code from a similar post: java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
       getWindowListeners()[0].windowActivated(
             new WindowEvent(
                      this,
                      WindowEvent.WINDOW_ACTIVATED
             )
        );
        this.requestFocus();
      }
  });   //where this is the current JFrame Object